# Generate two random numbers in a row won't work in C?

Tags: c, random

I am trying to get two random numbers in a row with C:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void testcollgenarray() {
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        int r1 = rand() % 256;
        int r2 = rand() % 256;
        cout << r1 << endl;
        cout << r1 << endl;
    }
}
```

Apparently, in each loop the random number generator is outputing the same number:

```
207
207
41
41
98
98
49
49
6
6
8
8
95
95
79
79
154
154
252
252
```

Comment: Typo: you're printing `r1` both times, instead of `r1` then `r2`.

Comment: Ahgrrrrrr, I need a rest, too much work today.

Comment: This code is also not C. Wrong tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    cout << r1 << endl;
    cout << r1 << endl;
    //       ^-- You're printing r1 twice
```

Comment: It's not about printing r1 twice. It's about getting the same random numbers every time you run the code.

Answer (score 2):

You should give seed to your random generation. For example use this line of code once before your random generation:

```
srand(time(0));
```

Which uses current time for random generation.

Comment: Setting a custom seed is also usefull when doing experiments, where you want the same random-numbers. The rule is: The same seed -> the same random-numbers.